# Adding URL filter regexes through Nutch Rest API

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, nutch

I'm using Nutch version 1.12 to crawl url's. I need to crawl only some specific url. I know that url's can be filtered using the entries in `regex-urlfilter` file. I want to know that is there any option is available in Nutch REST API to add dynamic url regexes to these file just like properties in `nutch-site.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember you can change the configuration (changing the `urlfilter.regex.file` key) but there is no way to directly modify the file (`regex-urlfilter.txt` by default). You could have different files and then change the configuration to point to a different one and restart the job.

In the past, I did something for dynamically changing crawl options (including the filters) from a Web UI. This was before we had the REST API. In that case, a custom component loaded information/configuration options from a database.